# combining python lists in savetxt

Tags: python, numpy, decimalformat

I have 2 python lists that I want to save side by side using np.savetxt().

I have tried:

```
np.savetxt('./filename.txt',np.hstack([list1,list2]),fmt=['%f','%f'])
```

but I get the error message

```
raise AttributeError('fmt has wrong shape.  %s' % str(fmt))
AttributeError: fmt has wrong shape.  ['%f', '%f']
```

I don't know if it is relevant, but the lists are in decimal.Decimal format.

What am I doing wrong please?

---

edit: I originally said "vstack" but I meant "hstack".

Comment: Why are you trying to pass an array to the `fmt` keyword argument?

Comment: I was trying to follow the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317840/savetxt-two-columns-in-python-numpy

Comment: @user1551817 That example works because the list passed to format has the same size as one row of the data array.

Comment: Thank you. If you see my edit, I meant hstack, not vstack. So my result would also have two columns.

Comment: Adding to @Carsten's comment/answer. You only use a list for the `fmt` keyword, if you want at least one column to have a different formatting than the others. In this case you have to give a list with a format string for every column.

Comment: Okay. But wasn't that what I was doing with my original fmt=['%f','%f']? 2 lists, 2 columns, 2 format string? Thank you.

Comment: @user1551817, just check the output of `np.hstack([list1,list2])` and `np.vstack([list1,list2])` and will understand the problem. If you used `np.vstack([list1,list2]).T`, you would indeed have a 2 dimensional array of shape `nx2`, and you wouldn't see this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a single value to `fmt`, like this:

```
np.savetxt('./filename.txt',np.vstack([list1,list2]),fmt='%f')
```

Example:

```
import decimal, numpy as np
a = np.array([decimal.Decimal("1.0"),
              decimal.Decimal("2.0"),
              decimal.Decimal("3.0")],
             dtype=np.dtype(decimal.Decimal))
b = a + 1
np.savetxt('./filename.txt',np.vstack([a, b]),fmt='%f')
```

The resulting file looks like this:

```
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
2.000000 3.000000 4.000000
```